# How to send file over wifi to another device without using serverSocket?

Tags: java, android, networking

I would like to save my file in SD card storage of another Android device over wifi using its IP address. How is it possible? I can send file to the device by knowing its only IP address. This should be done in Android programmatically using Java.

My code (so far) for sending from Java working here we can also send file but I tried by passing string :

```
 class main {
       public static void main(String[] args){
            try {
               String str = "hey sunny";
               byte[] msg = new byte[1024];
               msg        = str.getBytes();

               Socket s = new Socket();
               s.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.1.101",4044));
               DataOutputStream dos=new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
               dos.write(msg, 0, str.length());
               s.close();
             }
             catch(Exception er) {
                 System.out.println(er.getMessage());
             }
        }
  }
```

And so far I don't want to use this code on receiver side to receive data from socket, because I don't want install my app on receiver side like:

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private TextView t;
private Button setUp;
private Context context=this;
private Socket clientSocket;
private ServerSocket socket;
String msg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    t     = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.t);
    setUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setUpBtn);

    setUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    try {
                        socket         = new ServerSocket(4044);
                        clientSocket   = socket.accept();
                        InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                        byte[] bytes=new byte[1024];
                        int i;
                        ByteArrayOutputStream o = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                        while ((i = is.read(bytes)) != -1)
                            o.write(bytes,0,i);

                        String s = new String(o.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
                        msg = s;
                        clientSocket.close();
                        socket.close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception er) {
                        msg="error : - "+er.getMessage();
                    }
                }
            }).start();

            t.setText(msg);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You are using `Socket`. That means you are using TCP. That means you have to have a listening socket, e.g. a Java `ServerSocket`, at the other end. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

First things first, you should make yourself clear. tell what you exactly want.

- Your title says you don't want to use serverSocket, why not?
- You want a file on the SD card of another device, how are you planning to do that? You can't just send a file to another device and think it'll download your file. If that was the case all phones would be hacked in no-time.

If you didn't think of anything like this, then I think it is better to change your question to something like: "How do I store a file on another android device via wifi?" and then make sure your content contains:

- Information you already know
- Things you have already tried

Well, in the end, to answer your question, I think this guy has done a good job in explaining your problem:

http://android-er.blogspot.nl/2015/01/file-transfer-via-socket-between.html

Comment: I want to get data over wifi from connected device but i don't want to install app on them how will you do it :P

Comment: As far as I know that is impossible, think about all the insecurity that option brings with it. Ohh and you should post your code inside your question. If you really want to do it, maybe you can find the answer on a hacker forum.

Comment: Ohh, and because I can only comment on my own answers, I'll just do it here, I requested an edit of your question and added the code, if that edit is accepted (I think you can accept it, but I'm not sure) you can delete your answer with code.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to support hacking, but if you google something like 'android', 'hacker' & 'forum' you should be fine.